# TFPGList with record in objfpc mode

Tags: freepascal

I want to use a TFPGList with a custom record. It took me a long time to get alle the neccessary hints from the internet to get this little snippet compiled:

```
program Project1;
{$mode delphi}{$H+}
uses
  fgl;

type    
  TSomeRecord = record
    feld_1: Byte;
    class operator Equal(Left, Right : TSomeRecord) Result : Boolean;
  end;

  class operator TSomeRecord.Equal (Left, Right: TSomeRecord) Result:  Boolean;
  begin
    Result := Left.feld_1 = Right.feld_1;
  end;

type
  TypedList = TFPGList<TSomeRecord>;

var
  x : TypedList;

begin
end.
```

As you can see, the problem is to specify the Equal operator to the record. Furthermore this seems to be possible in delphi-mode only.

Assumed I wanted to write this program not in delphi-mode, but in objfpc-mode: What would the correct syntax be to specify the Equal operator to to the record? Is it possible?

My fpc version is 3.0.4

Comment: https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,47962.msg344745.html#msg344745

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(* Please try the following compiled with Lazarus 2.06, FPC 3.04: *)  
unit..
..
{$IFDEF fpc} {$MODESWITCH AdvancedRecords+} {$ENDIF} 
..
interface
..
type    
    TSomeRecord = record
        feld_1: Byte;
        class operator = (Left, Right : TSomeRecord): Boolean;
    end;
..
implementation
..
class operator TSomeRecord .= (Left, Right : TSomeRecord): Boolean;
begin
    Result:=Left.feld_1 = Right.feld_1;
end;
..
```

Comment: And `TypedList = specialize TFPGList<TSomeRecord>;`